# ¿Como lanzar evento luego de entregar el response al usuario en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Bueno básicamente lo que necesito es eliminar unos archivos de la carpeta storage, pero quiero que eso ocurra cada vez que se termina un petición.

Ya he creado un evento y un listener que se encarga de hacer eso el cual lazando antes de hacer el return en el controlador. Pero como puede que pase alguna excepción obviamente no se va a lanzar el evento.

Necesito que eso siempre se ejecute sin importar si se presente una excepción o no.

En la documentación de laravel https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle#application-events se habla de ello pero es en la version 4.2 y eso ya no lo tiene la versión actual.

Answer (score 0):

No das mucho detalle de como esta tu código pero básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es colocar tu evento al final antes de generar la respuesta y dentro de tu try/catch. De esa forma si no se genera la excepción el evento sera manejado.

```
public function SomeAction(Request $reques) {

    try {
        //Operaciones
       event(new CustomEvent($request));
       // return response
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // manejas la excepcion
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias ya lo he solucionado, hice un post pobre ello. Laravel 5 deja ese trabajo que dije a los middleware http://blog.furiosojack.com/2018/01/acciones-despues-de-cada-peticion-o.html